Django reusable Many-to-one definition in reverse
I'm struggling to make a Many-to-one relationship reusable.
Simplified, let's say I have:
class Car(models.Model):
    ...

class Wheel(models.Model):
    car = models.ForeignKey(Car)
    ...

Pretty straight forward. What, however, if I'd like to use my Wheel model also on another model, Bike? Can I define the relationship in reverse, on the "One" side of the relationship?
Defining this as a Many-to-many on the Vehicles would mean the same Wheel could belong to multiple Vehicles, which is not what I want.
Would I have to subclass my Wheel to CarWheel and BikeWheel only to be able to differentiate the Foreignkey for each relationship? Seems like there should be a cleaner solution.

You might look for concrete inheritance, so a Vehicle model, although that is typically not very elegant either.

If I understand correctly, you will need to "subclass" from a parent model. For instance, Vehicle:
class Vehicle(models.Model):
    pass

class Bike(Vehicle):
    pass

class Wheel(models.Model):
    vehicle = models.ForeignKey(
        Vehicle, 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='wheels',
    )

Now to access the Wheel instances from a Bike instance:
bike = Bike.objects.first()
bike_wheels = bike.wheels.all()


I never used it myself, but it looks like a use case for generic relations - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.1/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericForeignKey
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.db import models


class Car(models.Model):
    ...

class Bike(models.Model):
    ...

class Wheel(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey("content_type", "object_id")
    ...

bike = Bike.objects.first()
bike_wheel = Wheel(content_object=bike, ...)

car = Car.objects.first()
car_wheel = Wheel(content_object=car, ...)


In general, one should avoid using generic relations, because it makes your application difficult to port and makes your schema difficult to work with outside of Django.  Although, for this specific problem a generic relation makes sense.

I agree that it might be excessive for this situation. I would use generic relations for something like a "tag" or "comment" model that could be related to any model. Another common solution would be to make the "Wheel" an abstract model.

This answer seems to be a previous answer to another thread.
